# How to convert Java-objects for jqplot usage with Play! 2.0?

Tags: java, javascript, json, jqplot, playframework-2.0

I'm quite new to Play! 2.0, Scala and JavaScript (more or less) and I try to render my queried objects from the DB to some chart-graphics with jqPlot.

So far I have my Query...

```
public static List<UserAction> thisYear() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    return find.where().eq("YEAR(timestamp)", sdf.format(new Date())).findList();
}
```

...and my Result...

```
public static Result home() {
    List<UserAction> all = UserAction.all();
    List<UserAction> thisyear = UserAction.thisYear();
    return ok(index.render(all, thisyear));
}
```

...so I have the data within my view. Later I want something like this ([Date Axes Example with jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line1=[['2008-09-30 4:00PM',4], ['2008-10-30 4:00PM',6.5], ['2008-11-30     4:00PM',5.7], ['2008-12-30 4:00PM',9], ['2009-01-30 4:00PM',8.2]];
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
    title:'Default Date Axis',
    axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}},
    series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
  });
});
```

So I'm likely to replace the first array with something (months of the year/action-counts). Do I have to use JSON for this or do I have other/simpler alternatives?

I'm not really sure at all whether I follow the right approach or not. Some hints for how I should proceed or a little push in the right direction would be very helpful. Please ask if any information's missing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution of my problem is fairly easy and maybe I should use JSON for this (if not, tell me).

I will do it [this way](http://ketiljensen.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/create-good-looking-charts-with-play-flot-and-jquery/). It's an example for Play! with Flot and I certainly need to change it a little bit, because there is no renderJSON() anymore, but I'm sure this will do it.

I'm going to update this post after testing it.